# How to clear table contents in HTML without deleting data

Tags: html, html-table

This is just an example code. Is there any way I can clear the contents without deleting the data?

```
 <table border="1" >

   <tr>  <td>content 1</td> </tr>
   <tr>  <td>content 2</td></tr>
 </table>

 <button> clear </button>
```

Comment: you can just simply hide it...

Comment: style="display:hidden;";

Comment: `jQuery('table#my-table-selector').hide()`

Comment: If it is as easy as `display : none;` or `visibility: hidden;` on your td elements then give an id to your table. clone it under a document fragment and keep the original there. make necessary changes in DOM and when you need the original one just use replaceChild on your table's parent element to insert the untouched table back to the DOM.

Comment: i tried adding an id to my table and PHP code - $('#client_table  > tr ').remove(); but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try this... I think this is what you want...

https://jsfiddle.net/8bf0s0gL/1/

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('table').find('tr').toggle();
})
```

Comment: what if i use anchor tag? can i also apply the click function?

Answer (score 0):

well you can hide the contents

```
<tr> <td id='hide'>content1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td id='hide'>content2</td> </tr>

<button type='button' onClick='this()'>Clear</button>
```

just something like this for your idea